# Consolidating a large if/else list to show active or inactive menu items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, organization, slim-lang

I have a few partials - one for a main menu, another for a sub-menu, etc.

One thing I wondered for a long while. I know how to make active menu items highlighted, but take a look at this example:

```
ul.menu-list
    li
      - if action_name == 'change_password'
        a.is-active href="/#{session[:user_type]}/account/change_password"  Change Password
      - else
        a href="/#{session[:user_type]}/account/change_password"  Change Password
    li
      - if action_name == 'change_cell'
        a.is-active href="/#{session[:user_type]}/account/change_cell"  Update Contact Number
      - else
        a href="/#{session[:user_type]}/account/change_cell"  Update Contact Number
    li
      - if action_name == 'change_email'
        a.is-active href="/#{session[:user_type]}/account/change_email"  Update Email
      - else
        a href="/#{session[:user_type]}/account/change_email"  Update Email
    li
      - if action_name == 'change_notifications'
        a.is-active href="/#{session[:user_type]}/account/change_notifications"  Update Notification Settings
      - else
        a href="/#{session[:user_type]}/account/change_notifications"  Update Notification Settings
```

It's a crazy if/else fest. Certain action buttons (edit widget, delete widget) to only be available to certain user types. That would add another layer of ridiculous complexity to what you're seeing here.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the logic to view helper. For eg:

```
module MyHelper
  ACTION_TO_STRING = {
    change_password: 'Change Password',
    change_cell: 'Update Contact Number',
    change_email: 'Update Email',
    change_notifications: 'Update Notification Settings'
  }

  def menu_list_from(action_name, user_type)
    content_tag(:ul, class: 'menu-list') do
      ACTION_TO_STRING.each do |k, v|
        klass = k == action_name.to_sym ? 'is-active' : ''
        concat content_tag(:li) do
          link_to v, "/#{user_type}/account/#{k}", class: klass
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then just use it in your view

```
= menu_list_from(action_name, session[:user_type])
```